# How to copy one struct element from an array of structs into another array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I am trying to copy only one element from an array of structs into a new element in Matlab. I am new to Matlab, in C I would just use a loop to populate the new array with the exact element I want. Is there no other way to do this in Matlab? eye_record is the array of structs and I would like to copy just the x_pos elements from the entire array into win_x and y. My code is as follows so far.

Thanks for everything in advance!

```
a = 1;
win_x = zeros(length(eye_record));
win_y = zeros(length(eye_record));
disT = 1.0;

for i=1:length(eye_record)
    win_x(i) = eye_record(i).x_pos_measured_deg;
    win_y(i) = eye_record(i).y_pos_measured_deg;
    dis = (max(win_x(a:i)) - min(win_x(a:i)) + (max(win_y(a:i)) - min(win_y(a:i))));
    if (dis <= disT)
        eye_record(i).xy_movement_EMD = 1;
        fixation_counter = fixation_counter + 1;
    else
        eye_record(i).xy_movement_EMD = 2;
        a = i;
        saccade_counter = saccade_counter + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: As well as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801595/how-to-create-a-duplicate-array-in-matlab). Please don't duplicate your questions.

Comment: Also, I notice that you haven't accepted answers to any of your previous questions. Please consider doing so; it will increase the probability that people will answer your questions in the future.

Comment: I didn't even realize that was a thing. Thank you for informing me! :)

Comment: I thought that the last person helping me said I had asked the wrong thing and this meant I needed to re-ask my question. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. Thank you for the link!! It solved my issue.